# How do Characters learn new Artes?

Tags: tales-of-the-abyss

During battle i see my party learn new Artes skills however they seem to learn new ones more often then me (playing as Luke), there are also times where a character learns a new Arte from leveling up but most of the time its in the middle of a battle.

Also, i notice sometimes there are Artes in the Artes menu but are greyed out and it is only after a few battles in the middle of one that they get learned.

So i am wondering, how do characters learns new Artes exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of the [wiki](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/TotA_-_Luke_fon_Fabre:_Artes) (SPOILER) and what I can remember about the game (I played it some time ago), Artes are learned when characters perform specific tasks and other conditions are met such as number of uses of abilities or doing specific things.

The wiki is a spoiler if you'd like to figure this out by yourself, but it's quite detailed.